# Copying a folder from windows to linux using python

Tags: python, pexpect

Earlier by using pexpect module I could copy a folder using SCp command from linux to linux.

But when i am trying to do the same using pexpect from Windows to linux i am unable to achieve.

I have tried even pysmb . In pysmb i am able to read the contents of files  in windows and write it into linux machine.But I need to copy the folder.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is this linux machine? Dual-boot? VM?

Comment: winscp is available that is working similar to Linux' scp

Comment: I need to make it through programming way to use that code in Django 1.5.BTW the machine linux refers to ubuntu 10.04.program code is much appreciated

Comment: Should it be only for shared content or any file?

Comment: Which machine are you trying to run the copy command on, the Windows one or the Linux one? pexpect doesn't work on Linux.